# ng-submit not triggering in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got no error in my console, but my ng-submit is just not triggering. I debug by putting something in my controller, it did trigger, means it's not the problem of my controller not loading.. Below is my source code

```
(function() {
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('SignupCtrl', SignupCtrl);

SignupCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$window', '$auth'];

function SignupCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window, $auth) {
  console.log('hello') // triggered
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.signup = signup;

    function signup() {
      console.log('trigger') // nope??
   }
}
});
```

View

```
<form ng-submit="signup()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">First Name</label>
  <input required type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.fname" autofocus>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have an alias for your controller? like `SignupCtrl  as vm` or something like that?

Comment: @Mikki u mean in my route? no

Comment: @Mikki strange, I do $scope.signup = function(){ alert() }; it can work, why?

Comment: you have declared your controller without `$scope` but declared your view as if you are using `$scope`.  The controller is using the `Controller As` syntax, i.e. `ng-controller = "SignupCtrl as ctrl"`, so you would need `ng-submit="ctrl.signup()"` and something similar with your `ng-model` items.

Comment: @Claies, said exactly what I meant

Comment: @Mikki the boildersplate suck, enough said.

Comment: what boilerplate? you are using two separate declaration styles here, I'm not sure what this has to do with boilerplate.  If you don't want to use `Controller As` (though I'm not sure why you wouldn't, it's a much better design), then you would need to use `$scope.signup()`.  Either will work, but you have to use the same pattern in the JS as in the HTML.

Comment: @MariaJane, here you can find more details - [Code style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032), spent few minutes to read, could be really useful.

Comment: @Claies I used megaboilerplate.com and it gave me non-working version of starter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using 'this' instead of $scope failed in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313930/using-this-instead-of-scope-failed-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

### signup.js

```
(function () {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('Signup', Signup);

    Signup.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$window', '$auth'];

    function Signup($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window, $auth) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.signup = signup;
        vm.user = ...;

        function signup() {
            console.log('trigger');
        }
    }
})();
```

### signup.html

```
<section id="signup-view" data-ng-controller="Signup as vm">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">First Name</label>
            <input required type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.fname" autofocus>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="vm.signup()">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

As a side note, you missed two '**;**' in your code. I suggest you regularly test your JS code with a tool like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/install/).

Comment: what if I do not want to use controller as?

Comment: @MariaJane if you don't use controller you will not be able to access dom elements with angularJS.

Comment: @AshokShah means the boilerplate is broken?

Comment: @MariaJane can you update your full code the in question so we know what's going on